# How to receive custom payload in Dialogflow to my flutter app chatbot?

Tags: node.js, json, flutter, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I created a chatbot using dialogflow and integrated it into flutter but my flutter app can't display the custom payload in dialogflow can you help me fix this?

this is my json code from dialogflow:

```
{
  "richContent": [
    [
      {
        "type": "image",
        "rawUrl": "https://drive.google.com/uc?id= 19-CnfYQB3Mp7jK4O99k_M8hMqptBaP3b",
        "accessibilityText": "Example logo"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

i make my flutter app chatbot from this tutorial: [click here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/dialogflow-flutter#0)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to answer your question since you're not showing how you're handling the response from Dialogflow, or any examples of what you're getting back. The more you provide, the better our chances are of being able to help you. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: hi, i'm using rich content template from dialogflow docs for the reply on dialogflow, but the image not shown on my flutter app:
{
  "richContent": [
    [
      {
        "rawUrl": "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=19-                           CnfYQB3Mp7jK4O99k_M8hMqptBaP3b",
        "accessibilityText": "Example logo",
        "type": "image"
      }
    ]
  ]
}

Comment: Putting code in the comments makes it difficult to read. You can update your question and then post a comment that you've done so. Seeing not just what you sent back is helpful, but also how you are handling this in your app.